# resize highchart on load

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this event in my chart object:

```
load: function(){
    var text = this.renderer.label(percentage + '%').css({
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: fontSize + 'px',
        fontFamily: "'Raleway', sans-serif",
        fontWeight: 100
    }).add();

    var textBBox = text.getBBox();
    this.chartHeight = this.chartWidth;
    this.redraw();

    var x = ((this.renderer.width - textBBox.width) / 2) + 10;
    var y = ((this.renderer.height - textBBox.height) / 2) - (fontSize / 5);
    text.attr({x: x, y: y});

}
```

What I am trying to do is set the chart's height the same as the charts width. It looks like it somewhat works as the item in the chart is put in the correct spot but the chart defaults to it's 400px height.

So When my chart is 200px wide, the height should resize to 200px high. What is happening is it is moving the graph to the correct spot, but the chart itself is still 400px high.

What am I missing to fix this? I set my chart in the css to `100%`, so I want it to be the same height as that percentage. What can I do?

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epuqj6wy/

as you can see the chart is 400px, it should be a perfect square

Answer (score 0):

You can use setSize method. For example, chart.setSize(width, width);

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize

Comment: That helps with some things, and the graph is resized properly, but the chart is still 400px high

Comment: If possible can you add link to jsfiddle?

Comment: I have added a fiddle to the question

Comment: Nope, I need it perfectly square

Comment: If you are sure that once chart is loaded you won't need to resize it, you can try code below in load event handler.

 var size = this.chartWidth;
                        size = size > this.chartHeight ? size : this.chartHeight;
                        this.setSize(size, size);
                        },

Comment: At this moment you have "perfect" square, lets add a simple border: http://jsfiddle.net/epuqj6wy/2/. So take care about your other divs size, which seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to grab the container and reset it's height using styles.

```
events: {
    load: function(){
        this.setSize(this.chartWidth, this.chartWidth);
        this.container.style.height = this.chartWidth + "px";
    }
}
```